# opengl from window point to 3d coordinate

Tags: c++, opengl, depth-buffer

For a big project of mine i need at some point to draw a cube on the screen and i need to know if i clicked on a face of the cube. For that i know that i have to use the depth buffer. But the conversion i try to do doesnt work. Here is my code:

```
#include "Includes.h"
#include "Shader.h"

#define WIDTH 800
#define HEIGHT 600


using namespace std;


sf::Event event;


GLfloat get_gl_depth(int x, int y);
glm::vec4 get3dPoint(glm::vec2 point2D, int width,int height, glm::mat4 modelMatrix);

int main()
{
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.depthBits = 32;
    settings.stencilBits = 8;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 4;
    settings.majorVersion = 3;
    settings.minorVersion = 0;

    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Default, settings);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,

        -2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
        -2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,

         2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,

        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -2.0, -2.0,  2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -2.0, -2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,

        -2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  1.0f, 1.0f,
         2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
         2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  1.0f, 0.0f,
        -2.0,  2.0,  2.0,  0.0f, 0.0f,
        -2.0,  2.0, -2.0,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    glewInit();
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    Shader ourShader("shaders/default.vs", "shaders/default.frag");


    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Position attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // TexCoord attribute
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    glBindVertexArray(0); // Unbind VAO


    bool running = true;

    glm::vec3 cubePosition;
    cubePosition.z=-3;
    window.setFramerateLimit(30);

    glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 projection;

    while (running)
    {
        model=glm::mat4();
        model=glm::translate(model,cubePosition);
        view=glm::mat4();
        projection=glm::mat4();
        view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f));
        projection = glm::perspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)WIDTH / (GLfloat)HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);


        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        ourShader.Use();

        GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
        GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view");
        GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection");

        glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
        glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
                cubePosition.y-=0.2;
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
                cubePosition.y+=0.2;
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))
                cubePosition.x+=0.2;
            if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))
                cubePosition.x-=0.2;

            if(sf::Mouse::isButtonPressed(sf::Mouse::Left))
            {
                float x=sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).x;
                float y=sf::Mouse::getPosition(window).y;
                float z=1.0;

                glReadPixels(x,HEIGHT-y-1,1,1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,&z);

                x=2.0*(x/WIDTH)-1;
                y=-2.0*(y/HEIGHT)+1;

                glm::vec4 v=glm::vec4(x,y,z,1.0);
                v=v*glm::inverse(projection*view*model);

                v.x/=v.w;
                v.y/=v.w;
                v.z/=v.w;

                cout<<v.x<<' '<<v.y<<' '<<v.z<<' '<<v.w<<'\n';
            }

            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                // end the program
                running = false;
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::Resized)
            {
                // adjust the viewport when the window is resized
                glViewport(0, 0, event.size.width, event.size.height);
            }
        }

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So initialy the cube is drawn in the center of the screen and when i try to click on the left-top corner(first red pixel) i should get the numbers x=-2 ,y=2 but i get x=0.0150043,y=0.0150043 which is not even close. Where is my mistake? i followed this tutorial and read online about this topic:
http://webglfactory.blogspot.ro/2011/05/how-to-convert-world-to-screen.html

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41087929/opengl-depth-buffer-conversion) some hours ago?

Comment: Kind of, it was about the same program but different bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projecting means translating world coordinates to normalized cannonical coordinates. NCC is a 2x2x2 cube space. The translation from this NCC space to window screen coordinates is done "automagically" by the GPU, using the parameters you passed in glViewport.

So first of all you must undo screen-NCC translation. Use https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glViewport.xml formula.

Because window coordinates are 2D you can not get back the depth coordinate. There is an infine straight from your eye to the 2D window point and beyond.

Comment: Can you please show me how the code would look like? Ive got limited time to finish my project and i dont think it would take you more then 5 minutes?

Comment: @robertooverflow97 It's not so easy.. general solution is to use ray-picking http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-custom-ray-obb-function/ _Sometimes_, e.g. if you're using orthogonal projection and only one object to detect intersection with, the math might be simpler and done by CPU

Comment: I do have only one object and it's a cube.does that make it easier?